# First and second derivative of summation with inverse tangent

Tags: derivatives

I have the following following function and I would like to learn how to calculate the first and second derivatives with respect to $a$.

$$\left[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \arctan\left(a\frac{y_i}{x_i}\right)\sqrt{x_i^2 + a^2 y_i^2}}{\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{x_i^2 + a^2 y_i^2}}\right]^2 - c$$

where $c$ is just a constant. This is a formidable task for me being very rusty with calculus. I don't even know where to begin. Can you please give me some guidance on how to attack this problem.s
many thanks, Dimitris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go slowly and be patient. Considering $$F=\left[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \tan^{-1}\left(a\frac{y_i}{x_i}\right)\sqrt{x_i^2 + a^2 y_i^2}}{\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{x_i^2 + a^2 y_i^2}}\right]^2 - c$$ let us write it first as $$F=\left(\frac A B\right)^2-c$$ where $A,B$ are functions of $a$. So $$F'=\frac{2 A \left(B A'-A B'\right)}{B^3}$$ Now, set $$A=\sum_{i=1}^n C_i \qquad B=\sum_{i=1}^n D_i$$ This makes $$A'=\sum_{i=1}^n C'_i\qquad B'=\sum_{i=1}^n D'_i$$

Now, define $$D_i=\sqrt{x_i^2 + a^2 y_i^2}$$ $$C_i=\tan^{-1}\left(a\frac{y_i}{x_i}\right)D_i$$  which make $$D'_i=\frac{a y_i^2}{\sqrt{x_i^2+a^2 y_i^2}}$$ $$C'_i=\frac{x_i y_i D_i}{x_i^2+a^2 y_i^2}+D'_i \tan ^{-1}\left(a\frac{ y_i}{x_i}\right)$$

For the second derivative, we have $$F''=-\frac{8 A A' B'}{B^3}+\frac{2 A A''+2 A'^2}{B^2}+A^2
   \left(\frac{6 B'^2}{B^4}-\frac{2 B''}{B^3}\right)$$ with $$A''=\sum_{i=1}^n C''_i\qquad B''=\sum_{i=1}^n D''_i$$ with $$D''_i=\frac{x_i^2 y_i^2}{\left(x_i^2+a^2 y_i^2\right)^{3/2}}$$ $$C''_i=\frac{2 x_i y_i D'_i \left(x_i^2+a^2 y_i^2\right)-2 a x_i y_i^3 D_i}{\left(x_i^2+a^2
   y_i^2\right)^2}+D''_i \tan ^{-1}\left(a\frac{ y_i}{x_i}\right)$$

This is exactly the manner I should code it. We can save a lot of operations defining first things which appear almost every where (there are a lot).

Comment: Many thanks Claude for the clear step-by-step process. I would have never thought of this procedure. This is very valuable. Just one question.

Comment: You are welcome ! Just be patient and decompose the whole stuff in pieces you can handle "quite" easily. Cheers.